# MDX query result is different than Jasper Result

Tags: jasper-reports, mdx

I'm trying to write an MDX query in JASPER but the result is different from all tools(SSMS,SSRS,MDX STUDIO) vs. Jasper
the query is measure vs. a dimension and calculated total

the query:

```
WITH 
  //GET Average of TOTAL_MONTHLY_INCOME_VALUE FOR ROWS
  MEMBER [DIM_SECTOR_OF_WORK].[SECTOR_GROUPED].[TOTAL] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      {
        [DIM_SECTOR_OF_WORK].[SECTOR_GROUPED].[SECTOR_GROUPED].ALLMEMBERS
      }
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[Average of TOTAL_MONTHLY_INCOME_VALUE]
    } ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY 
UNION
     (
      [DIM_SECTOR_OF_WORK].[SECTOR_GROUPED].[TOTAL],
      [DIM_SECTOR_OF_WORK].[SECTOR_GROUPED].[SECTOR_GROUPED].ALLMEMBERS
      )
     ON ROWS
FROM [Model]
```

the result in SSRS,SSMS,MDX Studio is :
[image]

the result in jasper Studio is :
[image]

any one can help me of how to get the same result as the result in SSRS

Answer (score 0):

If you switch the set into the `WITH` clause does that help?

```
WITH 
  //GET Average of TOTAL_MONTHLY_INCOME_VALUE FOR ROWS
  MEMBER [DIM_SECTOR_OF_WORK].[SECTOR_GROUPED].[TOTAL] AS 
    Aggregate
    (
      {
        [DIM_SECTOR_OF_WORK].[SECTOR_GROUPED].[SECTOR_GROUPED].ALLMEMBERS
      }
    ) 
  SET [x] AS 
    {
      [DIM_SECTOR_OF_WORK].[SECTOR_GROUPED].[TOTAL]
     ,[DIM_SECTOR_OF_WORK].[SECTOR_GROUPED].[SECTOR_GROUPED].ALLMEMBERS
    } 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[Average of TOTAL_MONTHLY_INCOME_VALUE]} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [x] ON ROWS
FROM [Model];
```